# wrong position for second element in adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I have a custom adapter and when clicked, all returned positions are correct except for the second one, which should be 1 but is 0 (same as the first element). I have tried using v.getTag() instead of of using the position directly but it still gives me the same results. A little background on the adapter: my ConnectedDeviceActivity either sends "All", "No Connected Device" or an appliance name to the adapter. Based on the clicked item, it calls the AnalysisActivity, which displays a graph of the data related to the clicked item. Here is my code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AnalysisAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    private List appliance = new ArrayList<>();
    private List animation = new ArrayList<>();

    private String[] lookupName = {"heater", "dishwasher", "charger", "fridge"};

    private Context c;

    public AnalysisAdapter(Context context, int resource)
    {
        super(context, resource);
        this.c = context;
    }

    public void add(String newAppliance)
    {
        if(newAppliance.equals("All") || newAppliance.equals("No Connected Device"))
        {
            Log.d("Adapter", newAppliance + " added with position " + -1);

            appliance.add(newAppliance);
            animation.add(-1);

            super.add(newAppliance);
        }
        else
        {
            int position = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < lookupName.length; i++)
            {
                if (lookupName[i].equals(newAppliance))
                {
                    position = i;
                    i = lookupName.length;
                }
            }

            Log.d("Adapter", newAppliance + " added with position " + position);

            appliance.add(newAppliance);
            animation.add(position);

            super.add(newAppliance);
        }
    }

    public boolean isAlreadyInList(String testAppliance) { return this.appliance.contains(testAppliance);}

    static class RowHolder
    {
        TextView APPLIANCE;
        ImageView ANIMATION;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return this.appliance.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return this.appliance.get(position);
    }

    public void remove(String removeAppliance)
    {
        int removePosition = appliance.indexOf(removeAppliance);
        appliance.remove(removeAppliance);
        animation.remove(removePosition);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row;
        row = convertView;
        RowHolder holder;

        final int currentPosition = position;

        //Inflate row
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.analysis_item, parent, false);

            holder = new RowHolder();

            holder.APPLIANCE = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.analysis_item_text);
            holder.ANIMATION = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.animation_item_image);

            holder.APPLIANCE.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    for(int i = 0; i < appliance.size(); i ++)
                        Log.d("Adapter", "All appliance in order: " + appliance.get(i));

                    Log.d("Adapter", appliance.get(currentPosition) + " send to analysis with position " + currentPosition );

                    Intent intent= new Intent(c, AnalysisActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("DEVICENAME", (String) appliance.get(currentPosition));
                    intent.putExtra("STARTINGACTIVITY", "ConnectedDeviceActivity");
                    c.startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (RowHolder) row.getTag();

        //Display name
        String EM = (String) getItem(position);

        holder.APPLIANCE.setText(EM);

        int deviceID = (int) animation.get(position);


        if (deviceID == 0) //heater
            holder.ANIMATION.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        else if (deviceID == 1) //dishwasher
            holder.ANIMATION.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        else if (deviceID == 2) //charger
            holder.ANIMATION.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        else if (deviceID == 3)//fridge
            holder.ANIMATION.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

        return row;
    }
}
```

The log displays the following when I click the second element in the list (position should be 1). The results show that my appliance list is correct but the clicked item is marked as 0. The rest of the of the positions are correct. It might also be relevant to mention that the elements of the adapter are added by listeners in the ConnectedDeviceActivity which get information from an online database.

```
D/DailyAdapter: All appliance in order: All
D/DailyAdapter: All appliance in order: charger
D/DailyAdapter: All appliance in order: dishwasher
D/DailyAdapter: All appliance in order: fridge
D/DailyAdapter: All appliance in order: heater
D/DailyAdapter: All send to analysis with position 0
```

In my second attempt I added the first line after the holder and used index instead of currentPosition. The log remained the same

```
holder.APPLIANCE.setTag(position);

int index = (int) v.getTag();

Log.d("Adapter", appliance.get(index) + " send to analysis with position " + index);
```

This is the log for when the 3rd element is clicked (position 2):

```
D/Adapter: All appliance in order: All
D/Adapter: All appliance in order: charger
D/Adapter: All appliance in order: dishwasher
D/Adapter: All appliance in order: fridge
D/Adapter: All appliance in order: heater
D/Adapter: dishwasher send to analysis with position 2
```

Comment: You need to call `holder.APPLIANCE.setTag(position);` outside of the `if-else`. That always needs to be updated.

Comment: @SantanuSur this is what my Log outputs, the in order should be called 5 times indeed because I have 5 elements, Send to analysis only once (it is not in the for loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to get the click position of the clicked row in the list, its simple to get it. Change this line

```
int index = (int) v.getTag();
```

with

```
int index = position;
```

You are getting the position of the view in this method of yours -

```
getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

Just use this position as the position of your row.

Also you need to know what is a **convertView** in your **getView** method and when it becomes null if you are checking for *if(convertView == null)* in your adapter code.
[See the details here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)).

Comment: the index was my second attempt, in my first attempt I used the position directly. I will update my code to show both tries

Comment: just try to put a break point and debug. iterate every time through your getView method and it should print the positions from 0 serially, thats how its been coded in the Android SDK.

Comment: In the updated question, you are putting this -                     'Log.d("Adapter", appliance.get(currentPosition) + " send to analysis with position " + currentPosition ); '       
     only when your convertView is null, for the first time only.

Comment: Were you able to follow and understand what went wrong ?

Comment: I ran the debugger, didn't find anything, closed the debugger and ran the app again. It worked fine! Honestly don't know what the issue was but its working fine now

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are displaying index in this line.

*Log.d("Adapter", appliance.get(currentPosition) + " send to analysis with position " + index );*

Your *index* get updated only once here

*int index = (int) v.getTag();*

because *v.setTag()* is set only once when the *convertView == null* is *true* *(position is always 0 here)*

Now, this is v.imp -

All this code is saved into this

*row.setTag(holder);*

and retrieved like this-

*holder = (RowHolder) row.getTag();*

so no matter which row you click it will always print 0.

U can either print *position* or *currentPosition* OR update your index for every row.

Comment: when i click anywhere else except the 2 first items, I get values 2, 3 and 4 therefore I don't think thats the issue

Comment: I wonder, why your currentPosition remains 0 in the second item!? Hv u tried debugging??

Comment: just did, and for some reason right after the debug, I ran the app again and it worked! I did not change anything but for some reason it fixed itself... It works with the index, not the currentPosition